# How does proximity of a grounded conductor effect an electric / inductive field (and practical application)

Tags: magnetic-fields, electric-fields, electromagnetic-induction, inductance

My apologies - I'm missing a couple years of learning to be able to ask this question well, to know the right terminology.

Suppose a grounded conductor, such as a 12mm copper water pipe.
The grounded conductor is long, but not infinite.  Call this conductor G.

Another conductor, which we can call M, with an AC or pulsed DC charge is brought near the grounded conductor.
Is there any effect we can detect by measuring effects at M?  Suppose we can't touch G to do any measurements.

Are there *different* effects if M has a current flowing through it, perhaps an AC current?

In other words, I'm wondering if we can detect the proximity of a grounded conductor.

Since I may be leaving out important information that I don't know is important, a concrete scenario would be a grounded pipe hidden inside a wall at your house.  Can you make an instrument responds to being brought near the grounded pipe? "Near" meaning on the order of 50-100mm.

Please do NOT worry about "talking down to me" in any answer - I know little about this topic.

Edit - I asked about a grounded conductor, I should clarify I'm looking for an effect that depends on it being grounded, vs standard metal detector circuits which detect ungrounded conductors.

Bonus if the effect can be measured with a fairly simple circuit.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you heard of metal detectors?

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent Thanks for mentioning that. Metal detectors detect any metal, of course, as opposed to specifically grounded conductors. I have added a clarification to the question to clarify I'm looking at effects of a grounded conductor as opposed to a free floating object. Metal detectors do not distinguish grounded conductors. Nor do they take ADVANTAGE of the fact it's grounded to achieve better performance. A modification of one of three types of metal detector circuits might be effective for distinguishing grounded conductors